# ImageMagick - split the image into multiple base64 strings, instead of the files

Tags: imagemagick

I can split the image into multiple files by ImageMagick:

`convert -pointsize 240 -font "DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf" label:"Test" -crop 25%x33.333% output_%d.png`

I can also convert a single image into a base64 string:

`convert -pointsize 240 -font "DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf" label:"Test" PNG:- | base64`

But is there a way to split into multiple **base64** strings, and no need to create any files on disk?

Comment: Huh? What are you hoping to end up with exactly? 12 images as base64 all concatenated together?

Comment: Well, I would like to crop a image into multiple pieces, but in the base64 format. So that should be 12 base64 strings for the individual 12 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is along the lines of what you mean but it looks like a mess to me!

```
convert -pointsize 240 label:"Test" -crop 50% -write MPR:all -delete 0-3 \
   MPR:all -delete 1-3   -write inline:png: -delete 0 \
   MPR:all -delete 0,2-3 -write inline:png: -delete 0 \
   MPR:all -delete 0,1,3 -write inline:png: -delete 0 \
   MPR:all -delete 0-2   -write inline:png: null:
```

It produces a big pile of base64 stuff comprising the 4 quadrants of your image of text. I was too lazy to work out all the numbers for 12 twelfths, but hopefully you can see what I did.

An `MPR` is a *"Magick Pixel Register"* which is basically a named lump of memory capable of holding multiple images. So the initial crop at 50% width and 50% height puts 4 images in an MPR called `all`. Then I selectively recall the MPR and delete the ones I am not interested in and write the one I am interested in as an inline base64 image.

I guess you could pass the base64 through `sed` or `tr` and split it on the `=` at the end of each string and then use the result to populate an array so you can access each quadrant as an array element - but I haven't done that because, every time I do something useful, the OP comes back and tells me he is using Windows...

Comment: Quite complicated but it is indeed works. Thank you!  Actually I am trying to find the server-side solution on Linux, so don't worry about the Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out if your version of ImageMagick includes the delegates for encoding as base64 with this command...

```
convert -list format | grep -i inline
```

If the output shows a pseudo-format "INLINE" with a "rw+", then a command like this should work to do what you want...

```
convert -pointsize 240 label:"Test" -crop 4x3@ inline:png:output_%02d.b64
```

That will create 12 base64 files, one each from the 12 tiles created by cropping the input image with "-crop 4x3@".

Restore the images with a command like this...

```
convert inline:output_*.b64 output_%02d.png
```

I have IM 6.7.7 that can read the "INLINE" pseudo-format but not write it. I have IM versions 6.9.8 and 7.0.7 that can both read and write the "INLINE" format. So whether this will work for you will depend on your current version of IM and which delegates are complied in.

EDITED TO ADD...

If you don't want the base64 files written to disk at all, it becomes a bit more complicated and messy. Mark Setchell's answer should point you in the right direction. Here's a similar approach...

```
convert -pointsize 240 label:"Test" -crop 4x3@ \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) null:
```

That should crop the input image into 4x3 for 12 tiles, then output them as 12 separate base64 encoded text strings.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question to mean he didn't want to write just the intermediate PNG file to disk. I edited my reply to reflect my misunderstanding.

Comment: I think this updated answer is much easier to be programmed. So I may prefer this way in the final implementation.