# "-write inline" doesn't work anymore in the newer ImageMagick releases

Tags: imagemagick

My current workflow is based on the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664770/imagemagick-split-the-image-into-multiple-base64-strings-instead-of-the-files). But recently I just realized that the solutions don't work on the newer ImageMagick releases (e.g. 6.9.12, 7.1.1).

For instance, if I try to execute this snippet:

```
convert -pointsize 240 label:"Test" -crop 4x3@ \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) -delete 0 \
    \( -clone 0 -write inline:png:- \) null:
```

The returned message will be:

```
convert: image type not supported `png:-' @ error/inline.c/WriteINLINEImage/322.
```

I tried to find if there is any documentation to indicate the related changes in IM but in vain.

Comment: Curious, what are you going to do with the result of your desired command and all those inline:png:- base64 images that you want to write?  Where are they going to go?  Are you going to pipe them somewhere?

Comment: Post a bug report to the Imagemagick GIT forum (https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick) with a simple command such as `convert lena.png inline:png:-`.  I get the same error with that. Other inline tests that I tried also failed.

Comment: Yes, it's going to somewhere. The concept is being used in a PHP backend, which is simply use shell_exec() to call the `convert` command, and return the base64 strings to the web frontend to display.

Comment: As I said above, post a bug report to the Imagemagick GIF forum.